# How to match substring of key in dart

Tags: dart

I have map of strings which looks like this:

```
 var networks= {
    '62':'n1',
    '75,74,76,73':'n2',
    '71,65,66':'n3',
    '78':'n4'
  };
```

I have string `'0776556688'`and I want to see if the third and fourth digits match any key.

This returns false: `networks.containsKey(p.substring(2,4));` but `76` is a key.

How can I make this return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension on Map<String,String> {
  bool isInKey(String value) {
    final index = keys.toList().indexWhere((k) => k.contains(value));
    return index >= 0;
  }
}

void main() {
  final networks= {
    '62':'n1',
    '75,74,76,73':'n2',
    '71,65,66':'n3',
    '78':'n4'
  };
  var p = '0776556688';
  print(networks.isInKey(p.substring(2,4)));
  print(networks.isInKey('99'));
}
```

Result:

```
true
false
```

**NOTE:**

Structure suggested:

```
  final net = {
    'n1': [62],
    'n2': [75,74,76,73],
    'n3': [71,65,66],
    'n4': [78]
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

`76` is not a key `'75,74,76,73'` is a key.

You can do this:

```dart
 var networks= {
    '62':'n1',
    '75':'n2',
    '74':'n2',
    '76':'n2',
    '73':'n2',
    '71':'n3',
    '65':'n3', 
    '66':'n3',
    '78':'n4'
  };
```

You can also do this:

```dart
 var networks= {
   for (final k1 in ['62'])
     k1: 'n1',
   for (final k2 in ['75', '74', '76', '73'])
     k2: 'n2',
   for (final k3 in ['71', '65', '66'])
     k3: 'n3',
   for (final k4 in ['78'])
     k4: 'n4',
  };
```

Comment: I know this solution but this will be very long because I have an extremely long list. That's why I grouped them.

Comment: updated response with a way to group items.

Answer (score 1):

I would preprocess your `Map` to transform it into an expanded version whose keys are the expected substrings of the original.  That is, *generate* the `Map` from [mmcdon20's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68135659/):

```dart
Map<String, String> expandKeys(Map<String, String> map) {
  return <String, String>{
    for (var entry in map.entries)
      for (var key in entry.key.split(',')) key: entry.value,
  };
}

var networks = expandKeys({
  '62': 'n1',
  '75,74,76,73': 'n2',
  '71,65,66': 'n3',
  '78': 'n4',
});
```

and then you can efficiently do lookups on `networks` directly (e.g. `networks.containsKey(p.substring(2,4))`).